# MONO_WASM: instantiate_wasm_module() failed TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly'

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I got this problem suddenly when I run Blazor WASM project. I tried clearing cache and it removes the errors but when I refresh the browser it appears again What went wrong that made these errors appears suddenly in my blazor wasm projects? Note that it appeared on localhost and on server also https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK3ZI.png